# MacBook Pro 11,3 with dual Dell P2715Q 27" Monitors

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I have two Dell P2715Q 27" external monitors I want to connect to my 15" MacBook Pro 11,3 with OSX 10.10.2 ordered around September 2014. I've tried connecting it as follows:

note: tb = thunderbolt, dp = displayport, mdp = mini displayport

### First try

- tb 1 -> Dell P2715Q #1 dp in -> Dell P2715Q #1 dp out -> Dell P2715Q #2 mdp in

In this case the two Dell screens will only mirror, and OS X does not seem to recognize that there are actually two displays attached.

### Second try

- thunderbolt 1 -> Dell P2715Q #1 displayport in
- thunderbolt 2 -> Dell P2715Q #2 displayport in

In this case one screen will go on, but the other remains black and says there is no signal.

### side note

I also have an older 1920x1200 Dell display I want to use via HDMI for a total of 3 external displays, but I need to get an HDMI cable plus the first two screens working first.

Comment: maybe see http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-how-to-manually-switch-graphics.html#extdisplays I'm not sure really if that's saying they both need to be TB displays. For sure you cannot chain DP displays, only TB

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm considering the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

from monitor menu (the buttons) change the MST setting to Primary and Secondary accordingly

Comment: Ok, I see the MST setting, but how do I wire it and which computer do I set to what? I also found the apple info on 4k displays, which is somewhat useful. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856

Answer (score 0):

i'm using DP cable to usb-c on macbook pro m1 - usb-c end - it matters which direction it's plugged into the mac - may have to flip it, even though usb-c goes in both ways